# Implementation of Reverse algorithm LISP

Tags: algorithm, lisp, reverse, clisp

I am trying to implement the reverse algorithm in LISP. I am fairly new to the language so any help would be appreciated.

I have the following code in LISP, it seems logical to me but it doesn't output anything when I run it on terminal. This is what my rev.lisp file looks like:

```
  (defun rev (list)
     (if (atom list)
        (append (rev (cdr list))
                (list (rev (car list))))))
```

I run it on my terminal as:

> ```
> %clisp rev.lisp
> %
> ```

I am expecting the output **6 5 4 3 2** but it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 2):

You are not printing anything, so you are not seeing anything.

Replace `(rev '(2 3 4 5 6))` with `(print (rev '(2 3 4 5 6)))` and you will see `(6 5 4 3 2)` on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

You already have an answer, but here are some remarks.

---

Depending on your background and preferences, recursive algorithms are sometimes best understood with a trace of execution.
The [`TRACE`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_tracec.htm) macro can help you debug your code.
The exact output varies among implementation (here, I am using SBCL). 
Since I would like to show you how many times [`APPEND`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_append.htm) is called and because tracing standard functions in not allowed<sup>**1**</sup>, I am defining a simple function around it and redefining your code to use it:

```
(defun append* (&rest args) (apply #'append args))
```

The result of TRACE is the following:

```
CL-USER> (rev '(2 3 4 5 6))
  0: (REV (2 3 4 5 6))
    1: (REV (3 4 5 6))
      2: (REV (4 5 6))
        3: (REV (5 6))
          4: (REV (6))
            5: (REV NIL)
            5: REV returned NIL
            5: (REV 6)
            5: REV returned 6
            5: (APPEND* NIL (6))
            5: APPEND* returned (6)
          4: REV returned (6)
          4: (REV 5)
          4: REV returned 5
          4: (APPEND* (6) (5))
          4: APPEND* returned (6 5)
        3: REV returned (6 5)
        3: (REV 4)
        3: REV returned 4
        3: (APPEND* (6 5) (4))
        3: APPEND* returned (6 5 4)
      2: REV returned (6 5 4)
      2: (REV 3)
      2: REV returned 3
      2: (APPEND* (6 5 4) (3))
      2: APPEND* returned (6 5 4 3)
    1: REV returned (6 5 4 3)
    1: (REV 2)
    1: REV returned 2
    1: (APPEND* (6 5 4 3) (2))
    1: APPEND* returned (6 5 4 3 2)
  0: REV returned (6 5 4 3 2)
(6 5 4 3 2)
```

#### Basics

First off, we see that `REV` is sometimes called on [`ATOM`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/t_atom.htm) elements. Even though your implementation unwrap elements with [`CAR`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_car_c.htm) and wrap them back again with [`LIST`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/a_list.htm), it makes little sense to do so. Reversing a list is a function that is applied on lists, and if you happen to pass a non-list argument, it should raise a red flag in your head. In order to build a recursive function for lists, it is generally sufficient to focus on the recursive definition of the datatype.

The [`LIST`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/t_list.htm) type is defined in Lisp as `(OR NULL CONS)`, which is the union of the [`NULL`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/t_null.htm) type and the [`CONS`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/t*cons.htm) type. In other words, a list is either empty or a cons-cell.
There are many ways to distinguish between both cases which differs mostly in style. Following the above approach with types, you can use [`ETYPECASE`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m*tpcase.htm), which dispatches on the type of its argument and signals an error if no clause matches:

```
(defun rev (list)
  (etypecase list
    (null <empty>)
    (cons <non-empty> )))
```

You could also use [`ENDP`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_endp.htm).
The reverse of an empty list is an empty list, and you are in the case where you can simply use [`WHEN`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_when_.htm) and focus and the non-empty case:

```
(defun rev (list)
  (when list
    <non-empty>))
```

Above, we don't check that LIST is a cons-cell, it could be anything. However, the way we use it below can only apply on such objects, which means that runtime checks will detect errorneous cases early enough.

```
(defun rev (list)
  (when list
    (append* (rev (rest list))
             (list (first list)))))
```

The above is quite similar to your code, except that I don't call REV on the first element. Also, I use [`FIRST`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_firstc.htm) and [`REST`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_rest.htm) instead of [`CAR`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_car_c.htm) and [`CDR`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_car_c.htm), because even though they are respective synonyms, the former better convey the intent of working with lists (this is subjective of course, but most people follow this rule).

#### Append

What the trace above shows that you might have missed when only reading the code is that APPEND is called for all intermediate lists. This is quite wasteful in terms of memory and processing, since APPEND necessarily has to traverse all elements to copy them in a fresh list. If you call APPEND *n* times, as you are doing since you iterate over a list of *n* elements, you end up with a quadratic algorithm (*n<sup>2</sup>*).

You can solve the memory issues by reusing the same intermediate list with [`NCONC`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_nconc.htm) in place of `APPEND`. You still have to iterate many times this list, but at least the same underlying cons cells are reused. Typically, a recursive `reverse` is written with an additional parameter, an *accumulator*, which is used to store intermediate results and return it at the deepest level:

```
(defun reverse-acc (list acc)
  (etypecase list
    ;; end of input list, return accumulator
    (null acc)

    ;; general case: put head of input list in front 
    ;; of current accumulator and call recursively with 
    ;; the tail of the input list.
    (cons (reverse-acc (rest list)
                       (cons (first list) acc)))))
```

The above example is called with an empty accumulator. Even though it could be possible to let this function accessible directly to users, you might prefer to hide this implementation detail and export only a function with a single argument:

```
(defun rev (list) (reverse-acc list nil))
(trace rev reverse-acc)

0: (REV (2 3 4 5 6))
    1: (REVERSE-ACC (2 3 4 5 6) NIL)
      2: (REVERSE-ACC (3 4 5 6) (2))
        3: (REVERSE-ACC (4 5 6) (3 2))
          4: (REVERSE-ACC (5 6) (4 3 2))
            5: (REVERSE-ACC (6) (5 4 3 2))
              6: (REVERSE-ACC NIL (6 5 4 3 2))
              6: REVERSE-ACC returned (6 5 4 3 2)
            5: REVERSE-ACC returned (6 5 4 3 2)
          4: REVERSE-ACC returned (6 5 4 3 2)
        3: REVERSE-ACC returned (6 5 4 3 2)
      2: REVERSE-ACC returned (6 5 4 3 2)
    1: REVERSE-ACC returned (6 5 4 3 2)
  0: REV returned (6 5 4 3 2)
(6 5 4 3 2)
```

The shape of the trace is typical of recursive functions for which tail-call elimination is possible. Indeed, the recursive invocation of `REVERSE-ACC` inside itself directly returns the result we want and thus no intermediate memory is required to store and process intermediate result. However, Common Lisp implementations are not required by the standard to eliminate recursive calls in tail position and the actual behavior of a specific implementation might even depend on optimization levels. A conforming program thus cannot assume the control stack won't ever grow linearly with the size of the list.

Recursivity is best used on certain kinds of problems which are recursive by nature and where the height of the stack doesn't grow so fast w.r.t. the input. For iteration, use control structures like [`DO`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_do_do.htm), [`LOOP`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm), etc. In the following example, I used [`DOLIST`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_dolist.htm) in order to [`PUSH`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_push.htm) elements inside a temporary RESULT list, which is return at the end of DOLIST:

```
(defun rev (list)
  (let ((result '()))
    (dolist (e list result)
      (push e result))))
```

The trace is:

```
0: (REV (2 3 4 5 6))
  0: REV returned (6 5 4 3 2)
(6 5 4 3 2)
```

---

**1.** [11.1.2.1.2 Constraints on the COMMON-LISP Package for Conforming Programs](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/11_abab.htm)